# fax to pdf software

Tags: windows, pdf, modem, fax

Does anyone now of any software (preferably windows based) that would let me save incoming faxes (over a land line) to pdfs in a folder somewhere?

**Clarification**:
I think there is some confusion. right now I have a stand alone fax machine. I would like to add a fax modem to a desktop and have it pick up receive the fax ( I don't know what "format" they come in as) and drop it off in a dir preferable as a pdf but I can handle that later. my big thing is the fax to modem to file part of it

Comment: I still don't understand really your problem. Just get a fax-modem, install it, use whatever software comes with it, or some third party fax server, etc., and you are done. Most of fax softwares I've seen have an option to print the fax immediately. Then, using @anjogasa's suggestion will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it would be of help but you could consider piping it into a printer driver like doPdf (www.dopdf.com) which will takes print input and basically "print" it into a PDF.

Answer (score 0):

If your fax software saves the incoming faxes in a well-known image format somewhere, you can run a scheduled job to pick them up from there and use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) to convert it.

Example: [convert on linux](http://bitprison.net/jpg_to_pdf) (should work in Windows as well)

Comment: I think there is some confusion. right now i have a stand alone fax machine. I would like to add a fax modem to a desktop and have it pick up receive the fax ( i don't know what "fromat" they come in as) and drop it off in a dir prefrablly as a pdf but I can handel that later.


my big thing is the fax to modem to file part of it